# RxSwift - Construct the Observable using function inside transform function

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Here's my code snippet:

```
open class SomeClass {
  let driver: Driver<Bool>
  init(input: Observable<String>) {
    driver = input
      .map( { s -> Bool in self.convert(text: s) }) // error 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false)
  }

  func convert(text: String) -> Bool {
    // Do some complex calculation
    return true
  }
}
```

Explanation: In my SomeClass, I have a `driver` object of type `Driver<Bool>`, then inside my `init`, I'll take an `Observable<String>` and map it to a `Observable<Bool>`. 
However in order to do the conversion I need to call the func `convert()` inside the mapping closure, thus I'm getting the error

> 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

Can someone please show me how to get through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to move `convert` out of the class:

```
open class SomeClass {
  let driver: Driver<Bool>
  init(input: Observable<String>) {
    driver = input
      .map( { s -> Bool in convert(text: s) }) // error 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false)
  }

}

func convert(text: String) -> Bool {
  // Do some complex calculation
  return true
}
```

You should probably make `convert(text:)` private to avoid name pollution.